# WCF design pattern for website

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns

I am currently doing my first proper technical design for a solution to replace one of our existing solutions.  At present we have a variety of websites which nominally do the same thing.  However 3 or 4 of them use classic ASP and have never been updated as far as I know meaning the data they return is, at best flawed.

The application used by the majority of them is a SharePoint web part, using ASP.net (3.5) which creates several input boxes and combo boxes dynamically depending on where they are accessing it.  All of the config is stored in a SharePoint list (including the user name and password for database access).  When the user clicks the search button it calls a stored procedure, which processes and returns the data.  This stored procedure is the other primary reason for a rewrite, as it has been developed over years by many developers and none of them have commented what they were doing - it can take up to 30s to return a few hundred records and a lot of the time it doesn't even return what I'd expect *sigh*

So, I've finally been given the green light to rewrite this and I've come up with a solution in my head that I think will work.  However, when I am writing it down I am not convinced it is the right way to go, so I'd appreciate anyone with more knowledge than me giving it the once over.  The app will consist of the following:

## Website

The website will be extremely basic - simply creating the input boxes based on the URL they access it from and allowing them to submit a request.

When the user clicks the submit button then a request will be made using the ChannelFactory pattern to my WCF layer.

The response will be then processed and the user either shown the data they requested or an error.

## Communications (WCF layer)

We have two requirements, one for internet and one for intranet so I have decided to use wsHttp for internet using transport-level security and for the other possible use another protocol (perhaps net-tcp binding?)

This layer effectively only acts as a buffer between the outside world and the data, so it doesn't really do too much.  It simply calls one or more methods in the data layer which is next

When the response comes in from the data layer, it will either be data (good) or error (bad).  The WCF service will either create a DataContract object or a FaultContract object and return it to the website.

## Data Layer

For the data layer I am using LINQ to SQL to establish a connection to the database and process the request that is coming from WCF.  I am intending the data layer to sit on the database server, so it will be created as its own class library.

In the data layer the code will attempt to process the request and return an object to the WCF layer.

So thats basically it.  I am trying to make this system as secure as I can, as well as making it more maintainable so we don't need to reinstall the webpart every time we make a minor change.  I also included the WCF layer so we can make it more resilient, as it is a business critical system.

I'd appreciate any advice on where I am going wrong, or general comments :)

Comment: A suggestion to make it more secure would be to use a guid in wcf config file. and use that to authenticate against your methods in wcf i.e. AuthenticationHeader. Then you can give this out to clients :)

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been put on hold and marked down.  It's a detailed question about a discrete piece of work and I am unsure how I could rewrite it to split it down further as none of the sections make sense without the others being there.  I'm not asking people to design my architecture for me - simply whether a design I have come up with is practical.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty massive topic, but I'd say a couple of comments:

1. Use ASP.NET MVC for the website
2. Separate your concerns and use an IoC such as Unity to modularize the problem
3. Try using the built in AuthenticationService features provided in the Framework
4. Interface out the client proxy in the website so that you can hot-swap and mock test it.
5. Use Entity Framework instead of LINQ to SQL (just personal preference here)
6. Ensure you make your intranet WCF service use something as you say like netTcp and use Windows Authentication
7. Try using FormsAuthentication with your public WCF service to reduce the burden of your security needs. You may want to put in a custom message interceptor to set the Principal of the thread.
8. Provide interface variants of all of your message types IOrder, ICustomer, IWhatever and keep your boundaries very discreet for maximum modularity.

Anyway, thats just my ten-pence worth and the above has always worked for me!